# Addition on elliptic curves

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

assume $a$, $b$ are two integer numbers, and $G$ is a basepoint in an elliptic curve.

Is $(a+b)G$ equal to $aG+bG$ or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Point addition on an elliptic curve is an associative operation, and this rule is a consequence of that.
If $a,b>0$ then
$$
aG=G+G+\cdots+G,
$$
where the sum has $a$ copies of $G$. The claimed equation means that
$$
(G+G+\cdot+G)_a+(G+G+\cdots+G)_b=(G+G+\cdots+G)_{a+b},
$$
where the subscript indicates the number of summands. The identity then follows from our ability to move the parens around, i.e. associativity. If one or both of $a,b$ are negative, then you use $-G$ instead.

Associativity is needed for things like $aG$ to make sense in the first place.
After all, we have only the addition of two points available as a primitive operation. Luckily associativity gives us everything we need.
For example $3G$ could be either
$$
(G+G)+G\qquad\text{or}\qquad G+(G+G),
$$
and associtivity saves the day by declaring that the outcomes of those two calculations are equal.

Comment: Dear doctor Jyrki Lahtonen,Thank you very much Unfortunately, I did not consider this.

Comment: What did you want considered then?